# Where is the save game data for 140?

Tags: 140

Where is the save game location for the game [**140**](http://game140.com/) by Jeppe Carlsen?

Is the location different depending on if I use Steam or the standalone installer?

Answer (score 3):

### Linux

On Linux, the save game location can be found in the following directory, whether it is installed through Steam or standalone:

```
~/.config/unity3d/JeppeCarlsen/140/
```

Keep in mind, though, that the game is only saved every time you **finish** each level; you can't save progress made up to the checkpoints during level. And (hover to see spoiler)...

> ... after finishing the first three levels, you don't even get checkpoints any more. Each of the last three levels have to be done perfectly.